# Issue with z-index and positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the yellow circle on top of all elements, all my elements are positioned so my z-index of 999999999 should have put it upfront but it's not working for some reason, any help?

```css
.menu_maincontainer{width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column; overflow:hidden; outline:1px solid red; position:relative; }
.menu_contents_container{width:100%; height:auto; background-color:red; position:relative; margin-top:300px; padding:25px;}
.menu_background_oval{width:105%; height:500px; border-radius:50%; position:absolute; left:50%; z-index:1; transform:translateX(-50%);  top:-180px; background-color:red;}
.menu_contants_decorative_circle{width:200px; height:200px; border-radius:50%; border:1px solid blue; background-color:yellow; position:absolute; z-index:9999999999; left:50%; top:50px; transform:translateX(-50%); }
.menu_contents_texts_container{width:100%; min-height:500px; background-color:red; z-index:2; outline:1px solid blue; display:flex; flex-direction:column; position:relative; }
```

```html
<div class="menu_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="menu_contents_container" style="">
     <div class="menu_background_oval" style="">
      <div class="menu_contants_decorative_circle" style=""></div>
  </div>
     <div class="menu_contents_texts_container" style="">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its in a different stacking context. you see its parent `.menu_background_oval` has z-index 1 and the thing you are trying to make the yellow dot cover (`menu_contents_texts_container`) is outside that parent  and has a z-index  of 2. So it will always be on top of the yellow circle no matter how many 9's you put on its z-index. Remove the `z-index: 2` from `menu_contents_texts_container` and you will see

Answer (score 1):

Because `menu_contants_decorative_circle` is a child of `menu_background_oval`, which has a z-index of 1, the circle will inherit the same z-index. You can think of it as having a z-index of 9999999999 on a certain layer (z-index: 1), but that is practically the same as `z-index: 1;`

Changing the z-index of the circle's parent will solve this:

```css
.menu_maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.menu_contents_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 300px;
  padding: 25px;
}

.menu_background_oval {
  width: 105%;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 5; /* changed */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -180px;
  background-color: red;
}

.menu_contants_decorative_circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.menu_contents_texts_container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu_maincontainer">
  <div class="menu_contents_container">
    <div class="menu_background_oval">
      <div class="menu_contants_decorative_circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_contents_texts_container">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```